# How do I check whether my GSM Modem works in some other country?

Tags: rf, frequency, wireless, radio, gsm

I am a new to choosing RF modules and I am trying to choose a module that works in Qatar.

I see on [FrequencyCheck](https://www.frequencycheck.com/countries/qatar), Qatar is having GSM band of 900 and 1800.

So, if I choose [GSM800 C](http://simcomm2m.com/En/module/detail.aspx?id=74), having quad band 850/900/1800/1900MHz, will it work in Qatar? I am believing that when checking bands for say Qatar, you need to see whether 900 and 1800 are present in GSM modem?

Is there anything, I have done wrong? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on a lot of factors other than mere frequency band compatibility only. If your wireless carrier allows roaming to that country. If your device is unlocked. If the carrier in Qatar allows you access to their networks. Not all networks share the same frequencies in any given band. They are usually allocated blocks of frequencies exclusively for their usage and another carrier allocated another block to avoid interference. They might also use different signaling protocols and so on. Different parts of the world use different band combinations... If that weren't confusing enough. You can contact your cell carrier or modem manufacturer to check device compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done the same way. Checking the available frequencies in the destination country and then what your Modem supports.

What might as well be important to consider: does the network you choose support your modem / vice versa? i.e. what network will you be using and does it offer GSM on the supported bands?

In case you use your local SIM in Qatar: do they have GSM Roaming in place?

hope that helps.

Comment: Not sure, I guess yes. They say that the sim card, won't give you any issues. Can you share how exactly is roaming going to affect, connectivity? [Googling it, right now] I think, I can get approval to check on this one.

Comment: Well... Roaming must be possible at all. E.g. I know the MNO I work for does not add further Roaming Partners as he has at least one and up to three Roaming partners in almost every country of this planet. However your MNO, or the MNO of the SIM you are using, might not have Roaming agreements with the Network(s) in the country you are going to deploy your solution. Also I heard about m2m/IOT modules having problems with Roamign Steering (e.g. if your MNO tries to steer you into a specific partner network because it is cheaper for them by sending reject messages).

Answer (score 0):

You could research the type of devices used in Qatar based on reports and advertisements and see if the same of same specification devices are available to you. Cross referencing via available handset specifications would also be instructive.

Roaming agreements, choice of service provider or local network band limits may dictate which specifications are the most important.

So called "world band" and other trade terms are used to designate devices with wide coverage options.

Comment: I tried the advice you have given. I am still confused. The problem is I have to design my project from my home(South East Asian Country) and take it to Qatar for competition. I am not sure how to find a GSM module that would work over here. I'd be provided a sim card by faculties over there.
I am worried and not sure if GSM800C would work there?

Comment: There are may different data standards in use around the world on the GSM networks.  The bands are basically a licensing condition imposed by regulators but the standards supported are mostly chosen by the network providers.  I would try and ask the competition organisers for advice as they may have all the details required.

Comment: I already did. sort of.  Before asking anything, I had to take approval of professor, which he denied saying that "you're supposed to figure that out on your own". So here I am seeking help.